# Transition matrix to graph

Tags: graph-theory, markov-chains, visualization, transition-matrix

Is there a program that can, given a transition matrix $P$, draw a graph from it?

The transition matrix is also known as [stochastic matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix) and probability matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Graphviz can do that, I think. http://www.graphviz.org/